# Hide and remove margin on one class out of many repeated class names

Tags: css

So the below picture shows a list of many `components-panel__row` classes, but I want to be able to target just the one that is linked to the highlighted section.

So this code:

```
<style>
    .components-panel__row > label[for="post-author-selector-0"], #post-author-selector-0 {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

I'm able to hide the Author label and the selector, but the `components-panel__row` that is linked to those two, has a margin-bottom that I'd like to remove, but the problem that I'm having is if I do `.components-panel__row` remove margin, it will remove it from all of the class names.

If anyone could help me, I'd appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: You can do this with nth child css selector, but when if your list has another author? you could have generated a class on the author div and use that class to style according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child(n)` selector.

```
div:nth-child(4){
display:none
}
```

or:

```
.components-panel__row:nth-child(4){
display:none
}
```